# toLocaleString() changes behaviour after using toFixed method?

Tags: javascript

I was working on 'Formatting a number as price' problem on codewars and thought to have finally solved it with this code:

```
var numberToPrice = function(number) {
  if (typeof number !== 'number') {
    return 'NaN';
  }
  
  let newPrice = number.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}) 
  return newPrice;
}
```

One test failed because of rounding problem (Expected: '13,422.12', instead got: '13,422.13'), others passed.

When I changed code to this:

```
var numberToPrice = function(number) {
  if (typeof number !== 'number') {
    return 'NaN';
  }
  
 let price = (Math.floor(100 * number) / 100).toFixed(2);

  let newPrice = price.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}) 
  return newPrice;
}
```

in order to try to avoid rounding problem, to LocaleString didn't work the same. I got many errors like this: Expected: '245,123,215.00', instead got: '245123215.00'

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use `toFixed`, `price` is a string, not a number, so `toLocaleString` will not change it. Given that you have used `Math.floor(100 * number) / 100`, you have already converted price to only have two significant digits, so `toFixed(2)` is not necessary, and leaving `price` as a number allows `toLocaleString` to format it.

```js
var numberToPrice = function(number) {
  if (typeof number !== 'number') {
    return 'NaN';
  }

  let price = Math.floor(100 * number) / 100;

  let newPrice = price.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  })
  return newPrice;
}

console.log(numberToPrice(245123215))
console.log(numberToPrice(13422.126))
```

Comment: I didn't know toFixed changes number to a string, thanks :) Unfortunately, I still can't pass all the tests on my codewars task, now the above test passes, but two tests fail and again because of rounding problems - Expected: '-300.10', instead got: '-300.11'
Expected: '1,234,567.89', instead got: '1,234,567.88'
Do you have any idea about this? I tried Math.ceil() and Math.round() as well, changed 100 to 10 or 1000 and either these two tests fail or that one from above, I can't get all of them to pass...

Comment: @ivanmilenkovic that looks like they are rounding instead of using `floor`. `100` is definitely the right value to use; do you know what the inputs are for the failing tests?

Comment: unfortunately, they don't show test cases for this kata... this is what I get when rounding: http://prntscr.com/xmq9pv

Comment: Judging from the description, it looks like you might want `Math.sign(number) * Math.floor(100 * Math.abs(number)) / 100`. The reason that doesn't work for 1234567.89 is because of floating point precision; 1234567.89*100 = 123456788.99999999, so you could try adding a tiny bit of rounding e.g.  `Math.sign(number) * Math.floor(100 * Math.abs(number) + 0.0000001) / 100`. Otherwise you may need a different approach...

Comment: Wow, adding 0.0000001 finally worked, thanks! I was even trying with truncating at the beginning of the function ```number = Math.trunc(number*Math.pow(10, 2))/Math.pow(10, 2)``` but I still had one case failing. Could you please explain me this last formula you gave me, how or why does it work?

Comment: @ivanmilenkovic oh yeah, `Math.trunc` is *exactly* the same as that longwinded formula I wrote. :P The reason adding .0000001 works is because that makes `trunc(1234567.89*100)/100 = 1234567.89`, which it doesn't normally do because of floating point precision problems as I described in the previous comment.